# What is the need to use @dynamicCallable in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

I know there are two function in `DynamicCallable` that can be used dynamically i.e

```
func dynamicallyCall(withArguments args:[Int]){

    debugPrint("Test DynamicallyCall")
    }

    func dynamicallyCall(withKeywordArguments pairs: KeyValuePairs<String, Int>){
     debugPrint("Test DynamicallyCall")
    }
```

But I could not found the correct answer in which situation I should use dynamicCallable.

Comment: see this for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412536/what-is-dynamiccallable-in-swift/55412651#55412651

Comment: Also https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/134/how-to-use-dynamiccallable-in-swift